# Proposed Canso Spaceport, challenges to commercial viability of a private spaceport?

Tags: commercial, spaceport

[Maritime Launch Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maritime_Launch_Services) is proposing to build a spaceport facility to launch Ukrainian built Cyclone 4M rockets from Canso into polar and sun synchronous orbit.

Knowing very little about the space servicing industry, I was wondering how commercially viable a *private spaceport* would be, so I'd like to ask:

What would be the challenges to making a *private spaceport* commercially viable?

Comment: I've adjusted the wording of your question a bit to help it fit the format of a Stack Exchange question. Rather than ask for opinions, it's best to ask for challenges and problems to allow for fact-based answers.